# how to solve this query?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two textbox **textbox1** and **textbox2**

if `textbox1.Text` is greater than `textbox2.Text` then `textbox2.Text=textbox2.Text`

else if `textbox1.Text` is smaller than `textbox2.Text` then `textbox2.Text` is remains as it is ....

how to do that ....

Comment: BTW, `textbox2.text=textbox2.text` doesn't make much sense...

Comment: I think you didnt mean textbox2.yexy=textbox2.text

Comment: the question is above where i struck

Comment: try the method give by me hot this will help you -- do accept answer if it work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can compare Strings by using the String.compareTo(String) as Integer Function.

It will return an Integer indicating which String is of greater value.

```
If textbox1.Text.CompareTo(textbox2.Text) = 1 Then textbox2.Text = textbox1.Text
```

would be the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting integer value in your text boxes? However the principal of

```
itext1 = convert.ToInt32(Textbox1.text)
itext2 = convert.ToInt32(Textbox2.text)
if (itext1 < itext2) then
  Textbox1.text=Textbox2.text ' See above comment
```

Comment: This assumes that the text can be parsed as an Integer, using String.Compare as per Pranay Rama's answer might be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this method if you are comparing two string i.e to textbox string : [String.Compare Method (String, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

By Using ternary operator `?` Do this:

```
   textbox2.Text= textbox1.Text > textbox2.Text ? textbox1.Text:textbox2.Text
```